# How can I send null value to clr function?

Tags: function, clr

When I'm trying to create a clr function with nullable parameter (any kind), the function does not created in the DB.

Does anyone know how I can do it?

Comment: What database? How are you trying to create it? Could you post some code? At the moment your question is too woolly to really answer...

Answer (score 1):

DB: SQL Server 2008
I'm using .NET vs2008 clr functions

nevermind the code I was trying to send null to a date parameter, when I used the SqlDateTime type I could do it, it allows sending null (SqlDateTime.Null).

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your CLR function using SqlType parameters instead of regular parameter types, See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.aspx for a reference for the SqlType parameters that you can use.